# selectNodes alternative for crossbrowser

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

basically so far i have this code trying to make it work crossbrowser. im trying to get an alternative to selectnodes but getting stuck with it only returning one item in the array I make when there meant to be more (as works in IE an currently getting 7) due to erroring after first iterate next. im unsure if im missing something in how im doing this?

```
try {
   var oNodeDefinitions = XMLResponse.selectNodes("//Definitions/Definition");
} 

   catch (err) {
   node = XMLResponse;
    var xpe = new XPathEvaluator();
    var nsResolver = xpe.createNSResolver(node.ownerDocument == null ?  node.documentElement : node.ownerDocument.documentElement);
    oNodeDef = xpe.evaluate("//Definitions/Definition", oAJAXRequest.XMLResponse, nsResolver, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null);
    a = 0;
   b = 0;

    var nodes = new Array();
    while (oNodeDef) {
        try {

            nodes[a] = oNodeDef;
            oNodeDef = oNodeDef.iterateNext();
            a = a + 1;


        }
    catch(err) {
            oNodeDef = false;
        }
    }

}

 alert("a");
```